# How to extract data with bash script from many excel/Libre Office Calc sheets?

Tags: excel, bash, tabs, libreoffice

I have one question about execl and/or LibreOffice Calc.

We have the possibility to create many sheets as we need on excel and LibreOffice Calc :

[image]

On the sheet1, I have 2 columns :

```
Column 1      Column2
Monday        Monday
Tuesday       Tuesday
Wednesday     Wednesday
Thursday      Thursday
Friday        Friday
Saturday      Saturday
Sunday        Sunday
```

If I want to extract the first column to redirect them to a csv file, I can do  :

```
cat excel_file | awk -F',' '{print $1}' > my_csv.csv
```

But, I have in the sheet 2:

```
Column 1      Column2
banana        banana
apple         apple
orange        orange
lemon         lemon
cherry        cherry
strawberry    strawberry
melon         melon
```

There is a possibilities to extract : the first column in the sheet1 and the second column in the sheet2 with the bash/awk script/command ?

Fnally, the csv will looks like :

```
Column 1      Column2
Monday        banana
Tuesday       apple
Wednesday     orange
Thursday      lemon
Friday        cherry
Saturday      strawberry
Sunday        melon
```

The idea is to be able to extract the column what I need in the different sheet in one time with bash or awk...

Do you have any ideas to do this ?

Comment: Another way would be to write a macro in excell to extract exactly the data you want to another page (but that will be M/S only), or write another page that collates the data you want and export that page as CSV?

Comment: Are you saying that you can use `cat | awk` to extract data out of a `.xls`, `.xlsx` or `.sxc` file? I find that claim astonishing, since Excel and Calc files are not in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

You can only save the "current sheet" as csv, so you would have to save each sheet as a separate file.

Then in unix you could use `paste` to join the two files together by column.

Comment: Hello ! I Know this way, but it's complicated if I have 20 sheets. Big waste of time, that why I ask if it's possible with Bash/awk script

Comment: But your first problem is how to get the file out. CSV is not going to do the job. Change your question to make it clear  if you want to use something other than CSV?